# Send command inside screen from an other user via bash

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

Lets say:

I have 2 users: root and mc.
I want to run a command inside a screen which is located on mc, but i need to run the script as root.

This is what I came up with:

```
sudo -u mc -H sh -c "screen -r lobby -p 0 -X stuff "restart $(printf '\r')""
```

I guess, using 2 `' " '` wont work, so how do I manage this problem?

Comment: You question is more about how to nest quotes in bash than what your title suggests. Have you tried escaping the inner set of quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use double quote inside a double quoted string, just add \ in front of it to skip it.
`sudo -u mc -H sh -c "screen -r lobby -p 0 -X stuff \"restart $(printf '\r')\""`